# How to dump database in mysql using command line

Tags: mysql

I want to dump my database into one file with .sql extension using command line.
 I've tried all the possible actions suggested in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

```
mysqldump test > dump.sql
```

but it gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump gamescholar > dump.sql' at line 1

so why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

note--> the database is already there I checked it using show databases; command.

Comment: Run the "mysqldump" command from the command line, not from inside the mysql client. It's not an SQL command.

Answer (score 2):

you need to execute `mysqldump`  **command** inside **shell**

you are trying to run command inside **MySql Client**